# Why does the javascript snippet below not assign to LHS?

Tags: pentaho

This is my first attempt at using Pentaho's Spoon.

Input file: CSV as follows

```
last_name, first_name

     , Nod

 zanie, Rod

 anie, Slob

 , Vod

 meanie, Dod
```

Transformation: Where last_name is empty, set it to first_name
Hence the transformation script is

```
    if ( last_name == null ){
        last_name = first_name;
    }
```

Output file: Coalescent.xml

The trouble is that above replacement simply does not happen. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the field in the grid at the bottom and specify replace=Y if you want to replace the last_name field back into the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use a Modified JavaScript Value for your transformation? Try to add 
`return last_name`

Comment: Thank you, but the statement return was invalid, or so the engine states. I might have the wrong end of the stick here, but Codek's answer solved the problem.